# ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators, numpy-ndarray

I have two 3D float arrays in numpy that represent two MR images of the same shape loaded with `nibabel`. I want to compute a mask that represents the region of the images where there is no zeros in any of the two images. I wrote the following simple code:

```
nii = nib.load('./T1.nii.gz')
t1 = nii.get_data()
nii = nib.load('./T2.nii.gz')
t2 = nii.get_data()
mask = t1 > 0 & t2 > 0
```

I am getting the following error: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Why? I think the [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) o the operators `>` and `&` is correct. First `>` operators are done and then the `&`, so the `&` operation is between two logical arrays of the same size. Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I think `0 & t2` is evaluated first.  If t2 can't safely cast to an int type the error message you see would be generated.  <,  > have a precedence between logical `and` and bitwise `&`.  `and` would run after evaluating `<`.  `&` would be evaluated before `<`.  Brackets to force (or confirm) the precedence should resolve the issue.

Comment: `(x>0)&(x<0)` forces the comparisons to be first.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of your variables? Usually an `&` expression like that with numpy arrays produces an 'ambiguous truth value' error.  `t1>0` evaluates to a boolean array.  It's evaluated as `t1 > (0&t2) > 0`.  `a>x>b` uses a Python `and`, which cannot handle numpy arrays.

Comment: Your precedence tables goes from least binding to highest.  Comparisons have lower precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> `(x>0)&(x<0)` forces the comparisons to be first. – hpaulj Dec 5 '19 at 15:43

This was the case for other comparisons I've done, they needed to be encapsulated in `(` `)` if they were being evaluated in the same statement. So you can either evaluate them ahead of time by putting them in another variable or encapsulate them

```
nii = nib.load('./T1.nii.gz')
t1 = nii.get_data()
nii = nib.load('./T2.nii.gz')
t2 = nii.get_data()

mask1 = t1 > 0
mask = mask1 & (t2 > 0)
```